# What's the difference between 'attachment before' and 'block' in views?

Tags: views

Recently I followed a tutorial in views which listed taxonomy and gave me a short list above the view with hyperlinked first characters of taxonomy name. In this case, I created a "block".

In investigating the default Glossary view, I see the same hyperlinked first characters of title created by using "Attachment before".

Are there advantages of using one method over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Block** - separate views display that can be outputted in any region of the site.
**Attachment** - views display that can be outputted in addition to another views display, so you can attach this display to output of another views display.

Attachment has some special options like `Inherit contextual filters:Yes`, `Inherit exposed filters:No`, so you could use one exposed filters form for both displays.